# Javascript executing only sometimes (Internet Explorer 7 and 8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using 2 pluigins for rounded corners, one for all navigators and DD_Roundies for IE, the IE code seems to be executing only sometimes, aparently has nothing to do with cache as I clean it and again some times I get rounded corners and some times I don't.

You can see it [here](http://nzurita.es/demo/picon/solicitar-presupuesto.html) (try to reload the page some times) or [here](http://nzurita.es/demo/picon/index.html), where the grey div saying "Solicite presupuesto" should be resized according to the first instruction after the *else*.

It seems more thing of javascript than of dd_roundies, as the first instruction after the *else* is not working always either, this is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var anchoDoc = getViewSize();
        //if (anchoDoc <= 1152) && (anchoDoc >1024)
        if ((anchoDoc <= 1024) && (anchoDoc >800))
            $('#css-dispositivo').attr('href', 'css/estructura1024.css');

        $('#contenido').corner('bottom', '40px');
        $('#pie-pagina').corner();

        //El plugin jquery.corners falla en IE cuando el fondo no es liso, por tanto se usa el plugin DD_roundies en IE para aquellos elementos con fondo
        //de imagen o degradado (el motivo de no usarlo en todos los elementos para IE es que DD_roundies sa peor resultado)
        if (navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf('internet explorer') < 0)
        {
            $('#wrapper-animacion').corner();
            $('#solicitud-presupuesto').corner();
            $('.grupo-clientes').corner("30px");

            $('a.link-pie').corner('5px');
            $('.texto-destacado1').corner('right', '20px');

            $('#frmContacto .wrapper-campo').corner();
            $('#frmContacto .wrapper-textarea').corner();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#solicitud-presupuesto').css('width', '54%');
            DD_roundies.addRule('#wrapper-animacion', '10px');
            DD_roundies.addRule('#solicitud-presupuesto', '10px');
            DD_roundies.addRule('.grupo-clientes', '10px');

            DD_roundies.addRule('a.link-pie', '6px');
            DD_roundies.addRule('.texto-destacado1', '30px');

            DD_roundies.addRule('.wrapper-campo', '10px');
            DD_roundies.addRule('.wrapper-textarea', '10px');
        }
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you know that [you don't need any JavaScript to create rounded corners outside of IE](http://border-radius.com/)?

Comment: Try `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`. And update jQuery, current version is 1.6.2 and yours 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using CSS3 and http://css3pie.com/ for rounded corners. It's faster DD_roundies and easier to use.